# Re-install GeoNode

Tags: geonode

i´m about to reinstall GeoNode on Ubuntu 14.04 and i would like to keep all layers and geonode webpage changes I made (html and css changes). I´m saving some backup files and i want to make sure to have everything i need before uninstalling. So far i got the postgresql database backup file, and folders located in:

```
/var/www
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/geonode
/etc/geonode
/usr/share/geoserver/data
```

I´m new to this, so I´m not sure if it will work or not. Is there anything else i should backup? Will it work if after reinstalling i just replace some files or folders with the ones i saved (settings.py, local_settings.py, geoserver style sld and other data files?

Comment: If you are modifying source code it should be in git.  The geonode group has in place upgrade threads and documentation http://geonode.org/blog/2015/11/19/geonode-2.4-released/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I followed this instructions and it´s working fine
https://github.com/capooti/geonode/blob/migration_from20_to_24/scripts/migrations/migrate20to24/index.rst

After uninstalling y found this tool http://docs.geonode.org/en/master/tutorials/admin/backup_restore/index.html#backup-restore-geonode
wich would have been usefull, but it was too late for me.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You will need to make a backup of 4 things:

1. The GeoNode database (postgresql)
2. The GeoNode datastore (postgresql)
3. All the uploaded files from /var/www/*/uploaded
4. The GeoServer data folder

You can also keep a backup of settings.py and local_settings.py for future reference.